# How do I set a start time for a slide transition that overlays a video background in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Below is my code that works perfectly fine but starts the slide transition immediately when the background video starts.

> ffmpeg  -i background.avi -i IMG005.png -filter_complex
>   "[1:v]sscale=530x680,setsar=1/1[v1];[0:v][v1]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,20),-w+(t)*100,20)':y=20"
>   -c:v libx264 output.avi

I want the slide transition to start at a certain time and not immediately.
 i.e at 6 seconds. I have tried to set `setpts=PTS+6/TB` and also tried the `enable='between(t,6,10)'` but the image appears at 6 seconds and never makes any sliding movement.

Answer (score 0):

The overlay expressions have to be adjusted for the start time.

```
ffmpeg -i background.avi -i IMG005.png
  -filter_complex
     "[1:v]scale=530x680,setsar=1,setpts=PTS+6/TB[v1];
      [0:v][v1]overlay=x='min(-w+(t-6)*100,20)':y=20"
  -c:v libx264 output.avi
```

(I've simplified the `x` expression).